# Wordpress centered navigation

Tags: html, css, wordpress, uinavigationbar

Doing some tweaks to a sites main navigation.

using:

```
#navbarsecond {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #191919;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto 25px;
    text-align: center;
```

have got it almost there (can't embed images yet!):
http://i1298.photobucket.com/albums/ag43/sim888/SkTy/main-nav_zpsf7241a6b.png

Just trying to get the top & bottom borders full width also (980px)...any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers,
s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
#navbarsecond {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #191919;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
ul.dropdown {
    // Remove the float
}
ul.dropdown li {
    // Remove the float        
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mattcouchman, much appreciated - i gave it a go but unfortunately it didn't work. Here is a live test if its not too much trouble to have a look? [nav test site](http://223.130.25.64/~dashcrea/katecotest)

Comment: Thanks for the link. You need to remove the float's from your `.dropdown` and `.dropdown li` and apply the inline-block to the `li` instead of the `a` tag. I've updated the answer to show.

Comment: Amazing! worked like a charm - thank you so much for your help! commented out and edited the following as well as your code...Thanks again!

`/*.dropdown {
    float:left;
} */

.dropdown li { /*float:left;  */ display: inline-block;  position: relative; `